# Javascript file not being loaded alongside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Up until a couple days ago JavaScript stopped  loading with my HTML file and is making it harder to work on my project. I have tried clearing the cache, trying it on Safari and restarting my computer with no luck. Only errors I am getting are from the developer tools in Chrome stating an uncaught reference error (comes up when the button is clicked).
Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script src="GameManager.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="soloLeveling.css">

<title>Solo Leveling Game</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mainMenu">
    <div id="backstory">
        <h1><U>Backstory</U></h1>
        <p>A very simple game which follows the story line of Solo Leveling by Chu-Gong in which a player will be able to progress through various levels and dungeons to become the strongest!</p>
    </div>

    <div id="howToPlay">
        <h2>How to Play</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id illum et blanditiis commodi. Placeat eaque temporibus dolorem illo, officiis reprehenderit, neque fuga sint doloremque voluptate facere ut labore dolorum explicabo.</p>
    </div>

    <div><button onclick="playButton()">Enter the dungeon</button></div>
</div>

<div id = "gameBoard">
    <div id ="enemy">Box</div>
    <div id ="enemy">Box</div>
    <div id ="enemy">Box</div>
    <div id ="break">Empty Row</div>
    <div id ="player">Player
        <a href="#"><img src="Enemies/JinWoo.png" alt="Jin_Woo"></a>
    </div>
    <div id ="break">Another empty Box</div>
    <div id ="enemy">Stats</div>
</div>
```

and the JS as well:

```
window.onload = function(){
preloadImg();

$("#mainMenu").show();
$("#gameBoard").hide();
}

function playButton(){
$("#mainMenu").hide();
$("#gameBoard").show();

startGame();
}
```

Comment: `stating an uncaught reference error` can you be a little more detailed ... like ... what is the error

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: If everything worked until some days ago, but no longer currently, what has changed in between?

Comment: 1)there's no function called `startGame` - 2) it's unusual to load jquery after your code that uses jquery, 3) `function playButton` is not global, therefore `onclick="playButton()` will not work

Comment: @NicoHaase - I think it's a language issue, I think it means nothings worked for several days - and before that, this code probably didn't even exist :p

Comment: @Bravo Actually I think i see my error thanks to you haha. The main change was creating the window.onload function which in return affected my playButton.

Comment: 1.) Load your stylesheets before your scripts. 2.) Is the relative path to your JS files correct? Are you sure it is not `/GameManager.js` & `/jquery-3.6.0.js`. 3.) All ID attributes must be unique in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

By standard you should put your scripts the end before the `</body>` tag and make sure to put them in the correct order.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="soloLeveling.css">

<title>Solo Leveling Game</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mainMenu">
    <div id="backstory">
        <h1><U>Backstory</U></h1>
        <p>A very simple game which follows the story line of Solo Leveling by Chu-Gong in which a player will be able to progress through various levels and dungeons to become the strongest!</p>
    </div>

    <div id="howToPlay">
        <h2>How to Play</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id illum et blanditiis commodi. Placeat eaque temporibus dolorem illo, officiis reprehenderit, neque fuga sint doloremque voluptate facere ut labore dolorum explicabo.</p>
    </div>

    <div><button onclick="playButton()">Enter the dungeon</button></div>
</div>

<div id = "gameBoard">
    <div id ="enemy">Box</div>
    <div id ="enemy">Box</div>
    <div id ="enemy">Box</div>
    <div id ="break">Empty Row</div>
    <div id ="player">Player
        <a href="#"><img src="Enemies/JinWoo.png" alt="Jin_Woo"></a>
    </div>
    <div id ="break">Another empty Box</div>
    <div id ="enemy">Stats</div>
</div>

<script src="jquery-3.6.0.js"></script> <!-- jquery goes first so references are not undefined -->
<script src="GameManager.js"></script>
</body>
```

Instead of using `window.onload`, and since you're using jQuery, you should initialize your script as such

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function preloadImg() {
    // move your function's code here
  }
  preloadImg();

  $("#mainMenu").show();
  $("#gameBoard").hide();

  function playButton(){
    $("#mainMenu").hide();
    $("#gameBoard").show();

    startGame();
  }

  $("#howToPlay button").on('click', playButton); // took the liberty to add the event listener to your start button
});
```